# RESTful API design url

Tags: api, rest

I have end-points like these on my API:

```
 GET:   /users/:user_id/playlists
 GET:   /users/:user_id/playlists/:playlist_id
```

The first end-point returns all playlists for a single user same as the second one returns single playlist for a user, My question is, is it necessarily to have users/:user_id or just leave like:

```
/playlists
/playlists/:playlist_id
```

Which is better?

If I leave like this, I am considering to take the user_id from the post form...

Sub question of this question, what if the client for ex is logged in and make a request and tries to change the user_id, then he will get the data for some other users, how do I prevent such things from my API?

Comment: We have daily 2-3 similar questions, use the search bar (right top corner)

Comment: @inf3rno I tried to search similiar like this and could not find. could you refer me a similar link to that?

Comment: So you want to develop a REST API without knowing anything about REST in general. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have

```
/users/:user_id/playlists
```

and then link to multiple of these:

```
/playlists/:playlist_id
```

That way, you dont need to do the nesting.

Note that

```
/playlists
```

would show all playlists, not only of one user.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave /users/:user_id, since you could return other information about user from this endpoint and introduce new endpoints in the future.

```
/users/:user_id (main endpoint returning data about user)
/users/:user_id/playlists
/logins (this is example, you leave possibility of flexible design)
```